# localStorage loadVote when refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage, addeventlistener

I have a vote up +1 one time by user, now I'm watching. I need loadVote when refresh page, because saveVote is    running ok, I think of my solution is in return votes; of the loadVote function. And Where is ok the saveVote();, in the function once or after of  return votes;

```
var voteUp = document.getElementById('vote-up');

var handUp = once(function() {
    var total = Number(voteUp.innerHTML);
    total += 1;
    voteUp.innerHTML = total;
});

voteUp.addEventListener('click', handUp);

function once(fn, context) {
    var result;

        return function() {
            if(fn) {
                result = fn.apply(context);
                fn = null;
                    saveVote();
            }
            return result;
        };
}

function saveVote() {
    var votes = voteUp;
    var data = Array.prototype.map.call(votes, function(vote){
        return[vote];
    });
        localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log('saveVote');
}



function loadVote() {
    var votes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
        if(!votes){
            return;
        }
            Array.prototype.map.call(votes, function(vote){
                return votes;
            });
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('votes')));
}

loadVote();
```

Comment: You generally solve that by recording the IP serverside, otherwise just reloading the page lets someone vote multiple times. If that's not an issue, jQuery has `one()` !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vote only once (JavaScript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460685/vote-only-once-javascript)

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/08/vote-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: @adeneo I will use localStorage to save and load dates with JSON, but now, "I need vote-up once". Because now I can vote-up infinitely by every click that I do.

Comment: You can just disable the button on the first click (it means, inside the `handUp` function). But, note, all these solutions you just avoid the user of votes several times by clicking on the button many times... Because the user can just reload the page and vote again.

Comment: Even with localStorage, it's trivial to open the console and delete it, and vote as many times as one wants.

Answer (score 2):

love David Walsh's post on this [HERE](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-once)

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/905cd86a3e6bd3e101493d3e8bbcbfab)

```
function once(fn, context) { 
    var result;

    return function() { 
        if(fn) {
            result = fn.apply(context || this, arguments);
            fn = null;
        }

        return result;
    };
}

var voteUp = document.getElementById('vote-up');

var handUp = once(function() {
    var total = Number(voteUp.innerHTML);
    total += 1;
    voteUp.innerHTML = total;
});

voteUp.addEventListener('click', handUp);
```

Comment: You know to use localStorage to loadVote when refresh page?

Answer (score 2):

Simply do this:

```
voteUp.addEventListener('click', function(){
  //call your function method to what you want to do with voteUp
  //and call this
   this.removeEventListener('click');
});
```

Comment: You know to use localStorage to loadVote when refresh page?

Comment: Yes, there are many examples, but my probles is what localStorage save text, I see that no save +1 when I refresh page. You know?